# Java threads - cpu usage

Tags: java, multithreading, class, sleep

Here is a quote from a textbook I'm reading at the moment:

> "That is, whenever a thread needs to
>   execute a loop with a  lot of
>   iterations, it is good practice to put
>   a sleep() in each  iteration
>   - Event short sleep times, such as 5 milliseconds, can  reduce the overall
>   CPU usage of the application from 
>   100% to > 1%"

It's a good practice, I believe, but; doesn't scheduler does exactly that - A bit of time to *thread1*; suspend *thread1*; A bit of time to thread2...etc. I can't grasp such drop rate, anyone willing to enlighten me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You see this a lot in programs that update the display of something. It's called Busy Waiting, and that's bad.

If you have a loop that does something like this

```
public void run() {
    while(running) {
        gui.render();
    }
}
```

You're going to chew up your CPU when you really don't need to. Do you need to render it, over and over and over, 100000+ times a second? No, you really only need about 30 frames a second.

```
public void run() {
    while(running) {
        gui.render();
        try { Thread.sleep(10); } catch(InterruptedException e) { /* we tried */}
    }
}
```

This will limit you to a little under 100 frames per second, and you'll end up with a much better performance.

You don't always want this for processor intensive background threads, as you want them to have priority. That being said, if your background takes all the CPU, how will you process further input (like, I don't know, a CANCEL button because you didn't mean to start that intensive, hours-long calculation?)

So adding a small sleep to your threads CAN BE a very good decision.

Answer (score 2):

The scheduler does just that.
The difference is that the scheduler does it properly. Meaning that it will use the CPU efficiently, and that's why you'll get a good CPU usage.

I don't see anything bad about it. It just means it's working.

When you let it sleep there will be more idle time, and you'll reduce CPU usage. If that is you goal for some reason.
High CPU usage isn't harmful (unless you get over-heating in which case you have a hardware problem).

Usually when I approach multi-threading problems I actually aim for a high CPU usage. This usually means that the problem is divided evenly between the threads and I'm getting the maximum from the CPU.

If you're using 1% of the CPU it means it's not working, so why have such a good computer ? You should take advantage of the hardware.

Comment: Joshua Bloch's Effective Java Item 72: Don't depend on the thread Scheduler. It does NOT do it properly. Quote "Threads should not run if they aren't doing useful work." and "Threads should not busy wait."

Comment: I never said you should busy wait. There's a great difference between "loop with many iterations" and busy wait. If it's a finite number of iterations, we want it to finish, if it's a busy wait (infinite number) then we can let it sleep

Answer (score 2):

When your program does number-crunching (or other cpu intensive tasks) you want it to run at 100%, don't you?

OTOH, if your program is waiting for input, then you should use asynchronous programming as much as possible and not run endlessly in a loop (asynchronous = system calls you).

Comment: You're right. That isn't mentioned. I'll discuss with teacher tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Forget it. What does limiting the CPU usage to 1% buy you? **Nothing at all?**

Limiting the CPU usage by a factor of 100 means in general slowing down the app by the factor.

You may want it in case there are other more important threads or in case you may want to stop this thread using `Thread.interrupt()`, but both can be achieved otherwise.

Comment: Umm, it buys the ability to use other programs at the same time. Most threads with loops don't need to run constantly. They can benefit from a break.

Comment: I can run many other programs at the same time. With Linux, the CPU hungry process internally gets low priority, so I don't care much. Moreover, currently there are multiple cores in most computers.

Comment: Regardless, it will take up an entire core. You don't have direct control over the priority in the app, and if you do it through the OS, it's still just a suggestion. This is a symptom of Busy Waiting, and is a very serious performance problem.

Comment: Suggestion? Whatever you use, get a real OS. Some long time ago, I had running 3-5 low priority computations on my 2-core PC for weeks without really disturbing me. As for busy waiting - it's wrong most of the time, but nobody was speaking about it before you.

Comment: I cannot imagine an elementary Java textbook utilizing threads in any other way than gui loops (and, that is the most common thread that would have any kind of iteration that wouldn't block on its own otherwise.) It's also my experience that beginner Java programmers (especially those reading textbooks) implement their gui with a non-blocking loop causing endless rendering. And is it my fault no one else connected the dots to see what the author of the textbook was getting at? It's worth noting OP actually changed his accepted answer to mine after I posted it.

Comment: OK, your explanation what this stupid textbook is about is probably right.

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard of such practise, however it would probably result in *huge* drop in CPU usage. This is because the "bits" of time that scheduler gives for every threads are very small, so that 5ms is considerable amount of time comparing to that.

With that said, I see one place you could benefit from such slowing down of your thread: responsiveness on single-core machines.